# Add admin tab in prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to add some menus on the Prestashop admin sidebar.
how to add a category title like "BLOG" on this below picture?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's all well explained in the official devdocs :

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/tabs/#tabs-registration

Comment: No, it's not "well explained". There are many problems, for example if you want a root tab, it will display the root menu as well under the sub menu.